# An issue with quotes in a bash call of a function

Tags: bash, xargs

I wrote a small bash script that looks round about like this:

```
VAR1="test"
VAR2="test2"

letsDoSomeStuff() {
echo $1
echo $2
echo $3`
}



fswatch -0 . | xargs -0 -n 1 -I {} bash -c 'letsDoSomeStuff {} "$VAR1 $VAR2"'
```

What I want to do, is to look for changes in a folder (via the swatch) and then do some stuff with the changed files in a function in the bash script. Unfortunately, I need to pass on the $VAR1 and $VAR2 as parameters as they don't "survive" the xargs call.

The bash scripts works fine. However, $VAR1 and $VAR2 are not properly passed on to the function. When I start the script, it outputs for every changed file:

```
   filename
empty line
empty line
```

Can anybody here help me out with this call? I guess I'm messing up the single and double quotes but can't find the right way.

Thanks in advance

Norbert

Comment: Having $VAR1 and $VAR2 together in single quotes turns them into one token, so they'll be considered as a single argument to letsDoSomeStuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass in parameters to your function call:

```
fswatch -0 . | 
xargs -0 -n 1 -I {} bash -c 'letsDoSomeStuff "$1" "$2" "$3"' - {} "$VAR1" "$VAR2"
```

Comment: So wonderfull. It works! I had to leave out the - though. My solution is fswatch -0 . | 
xargs -0 -n 1 -I {} bash -c 'letsDoSomeStuff "$1" "$2" "$3"' {} "$VAR1" "$VAR2"

Comment: Yes you can leave `-` that is for setting `$0`